# Not to lose data on database operations if disconnected

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection

I need to know how I would not lose data already entered by a user if disconnected. For example, one user fills out  a form completely with no required inputs left blank. As he presses the SAVE button, before data are stored in the database the connection to the internet (as it is an internet app) would be disconnected. Regularly, no data would be saved and all of the operations would be rolled back.
**My question: Is there any way in an ASP.NET C# application to preserve those inputs data? and when the connection comes back even if the app (browser) is closed or even the machine is shut down the operation gets completed?**
Many thanks for any kind assistance

Comment: Not using C#, because that runs on the server. But on the client, HTML5 provides [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Or you could save it in a [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). You'll need to use some JavaScript to save your data in one of those when the form submits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, partially Yes.

As mason commented, You can use LocalStorage of the browser to store the data on the client-side in case the internet connection is not available.

There is no way you can tackle this problem in C# because it runs on the server and if the connection goes off, any data from the client would not reach to the server and hence no server-side code will be executed.

You can adapt the following pattern to accomplish this using LocalStorage:

**Pseudo-code**

```
//Flag
Bool Internet_Available=false;


// on internet connected
if(data available in LocalStorage){
     Internet_Available=true;
     //submit the data to server
}

// on internet disconnected
Internet_Available=false;



// on submit
If(Internet_Available){       
    // submit form
}
else{
    // save the form values in LocalStorage
    // alert user
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: many thanks to you and mason. Actually, the pseudo-code you've written can do the job for me. Buy you know, at first I intended to continue the database operation automatically after reconnecting. But at this time, for the specific scenarios that I've been dealing with actually there is no need to do it automatically and simply the LocalStorage manner would meets the client's requirements properly. So, many thanks for your helps.